# create a query in Visual Studio Team Service with unassigned bugs

Tags: tfs, azure-devops

How can i create a query for list bugs which are unassigned for current sprint

I tried setting `assigned to` empty with `=` operator and `contains` operator

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Leaving the assigned to value empty in the query will give you the work items which are unassigned.
The query you want should be like this:

Assigned To =

And Work Item Type = Bug

And Iteration Path = @CurrentIteration